# jQuery - How to populate a div in another page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been banging my head around for a while, so I will make it as simple as possible: on a form submission on page A, I want to load the content of a page B inside a div on page C.
Example:

login.html

```
<form id="test" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="user"/>
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="login"/>
</form>
```

user.php

```
<?php
  echo "Hello, ".$_POST['user'];
?>
```

index.html

```
<body>
 <div id="target"></div>
</body>
```

Final result (index.html)

"Hello, JohnDoe"

shall I use the load() method with the URL as first selector?

```
$('#test').submit(function() {
 $('index.html#target').load('user.php');
});
```

P. S.: all pages are on the same domain.

P. P. S.: I said INSIDE a different page, not FROM a different page.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use SESSIONS?

Comment: I hope you have a padded wall so your head is well protected from the banging :)

Comment: Actually _I do_ use sessions, but I also need to populate the "target" div inside index.html.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to need a change

```
$('index.html#target').load('user.php');
```

to

```
$('#target').load('user.php');
```

EDIT:  ok, I am going to add in some, hopefully useful code with some very basic markup.  This is not specific to your code, but the concept should be useful and it is testable with only a couple of html pages, nothing fancy.

What I will illustrate is how to call script from one page, from another page.  I will have one page/window that I will call the Main page, and another the Child page.  None of this is very fancy markup.

They will interact using some very basic script calls, even passing information back and forth to eachc other.   I will present first the markup of each, then the script in each.  Each page has jQuery linked in the header.

My main point here is that you could use a modified version of this to tell one page to do something using script/actions instantiated from anther page, as long as you get a reference to each page.  I use the window open and window.opener for this reference in my example.

Main page markup: Page is "TestCallbackmain.html'

```
<body>
    <div class='pagetop'>
        Test Callback Main
    </div>
    <div class='pageDetailContainer'>
        <div class='pageDetail'>
            Move on folks, nothing to see here
            <div id='detailContent'>
            </div>
            <button id='closeChildy'>
                Close Childy Window</button>
            <button id='openChildy'>
                Open Childy Window</button>
            <div id='childSees'>
                me empty</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Child page markup:  This is called '"TestCallBack.html'

```
<body>
    <div class='pagetop'>
        Test Callback Child
    </div>
    <div class='pageDetailContainer'>
        <div class='pageDetail'>
            <div id="achildy">
                HereIBe
                <div id="inchildy">
                    I am childy text
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id='pleaseKillMe'>
                Have Parent Close Me</button>
            <div id='textHolder'>
            </div>
            <div id='callbackTextHold'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    Howdy
</body>
```

Main page script:

```
function logNewWindow(newWindow, JQnewWindowDoc) {
    var mychildText = JQnewWindowDoc.text(); //all the child doc text
    var innerChildText = $("#inchildy", JQnewWindowDoc).text(); // one element text
    var gotback = newWindow.childCallBack("CHILD TEXT:" + mychildText + " INNER:" + innerChildText);
    $('#callbackTextHold').text("GOT:" + gotback); //child sent me this text from childCallBack
};

var AWindow;
function openChild() {
    AWindow = window.open("TestCallBack.html");
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#detailContent').text('Loaded JQ');
    $('#closeChildy').click(function() {
        AWindow.close();
    });
    $('#openChildy').click(function(e) {
        openChild();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

Child page script:

```
var ct;
function childCallBack(passstuff) {
    $('#textHolder').html('ct:"' + ct + '"<br /> CHILD GOT:(' + passstuff + ")");
    return ct;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    ct = $("#achildy").text();
    window.opener.logNewWindow(window, $(document));

    $('#childSees', window.opener.document).text('You been Had by child');

    $('#pleaseKillMe').click(function() {
        $('#closeChildy', window.opener.document).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: So the first selector is related to the destination page, not the starting one?

Comment: 'index.html#target' is simply not a valid selector of a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('index.html#target').load('user.php')` to `$('#target').load('user.php');`

If you want to get div with id `target` from `user.php` use this code:

```
$('#target').load('user.php #targer');
```

But you probably want to send post request?

```
$.post('user.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data){
    $("#target").html(data)
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Things to learn:

- http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
- http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: Yesss! I was looking for something like that! But in the first example, how does the script understand that #target is in "user.php" and not in "login.index"? (Just curiosity)

Comment: When you append div id after after filename in jQuery `load` method jQuey loads file with specified filename and finds div with specified id

Comment: But #target is in "index.html", not in "user.php". "user.php" only contains code to be executed by the server and injected in the DOM of the static "index.html" page.

Comment: Look at the updated 2nd example. That's probably what you need. It sends data from you form to `user.php` and loads output to the layer with id `target`

Comment: I need to load the main PHP page inside a "target" div that is inside a static HTML page. I can easily do it with th load() method from inside the HTML page, but this time I need to do that from an _external_ login page. 
I can see no reference to "index.html" in your code, am I missing something?

Comment: You want to replace contents of login.html with contents of index.html?

Comment: No, I want to put the contents of user.php **inside** index.html on login.html "submit" event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15070/discussion-between-daniil-and-marziobs)

Answer (score 0):

The best would probably be to do it server-side.

In index.html (wich should be index.php) you do as follow :

```
<body>
    <div id="target">
         <?php include 'user.php';
    ?></div>
</body>
```

In login.html the form should be set like this :

```
<form id="test" action="index.php" method="post">
```

Notice that no js or jQuery is necessary.

Comment: I would add that some php framework exist. Those frameworks will help you by providing a good architecture for you website.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using jQuery. The OP most likely wants to load a page in another from a user action instead of having it present on page load. For what the OP _wants_ to do, JS is required.

Comment: For dynamically added content, yes jQuery is necessary and the JohnDoe answer is the good one. But if the OP don't want to make it dynamically (after the page load) my answer should be preferred.

Comment: Many reasons: index.html is full and heavy with graphics, js and css, so I want to load it only once, using small PHP files to populate/refresh the same target div. That's what AJAX is about, isn'it it?

Comment: For your needs, I agree AJAX is the way.

Answer (score 0):

user.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if($_POST && $_POST['user']):
      if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])):
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
        echo $_SESSION['user'];
      endif;
    elseif(isset($_SESSION['user'])):
      echo $_SESSION['user'];
    else:
      echo 'How did you get to this page?';
    endif;
?>
```

Load the file as expected. If there's form data posted to the file, you'll return it. If there's no form data, but the form had been previously submitted, sessions will catch that and output the username. If they never submit the form, but requested the page anyway, they'll get 'How did you get to this page'?

Comment: Okay, the original is quite similar to this, but how do I send this to the "target" div inside index.html, _from_ login.html?

Comment: @marziobs If we're on `page A (index.html)`, and we send the form data to `page B (user.php`, and we want the data to load into `page C (login.html)`, then you'll have to ensure that `page C` was opened by `page A`. Otherwise `javascript will have no access to it`, and more over; you'll have to use `window.open` to create `page C` or...well, `javascript will have no access to it`