# Call DIV From other PHP Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, authentication

I try search but nothing answer like what i want.. Okay here my problem.

I have login page called index.php and inside index.php have div for information login.

index.php

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>

<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST">
    <p>Username <input type="text" name="cUsername" size="20"></p>
    <p>Password <input type="text" name="cPassword" size="20"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" name="B1"></p>
</form>

<div id="msg"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and here my Jquery that login without refresh page.

login.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Loading4').hide();    
});

function ajax-login(){

    var cUusername = $("#cUsername").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    if(cUsername.length > 2){
        $('#Loading4').show();
        $.post("login.php", {
            cUsername: $('#cUsername').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
        }, function(response){
            $('#Info4').fadeOut();
             $('#Loading4').hide();
            setTimeout("finishAjax4('Info4', '"+escape(response)+"')", 450);
        });
        return false;
    }
}

function finishAjax4(id, response){

  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

and here my login page called

login.php

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST)
{
    $username   = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $query = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".strtolower($username)."'";
    $results = mysql_query( $query) or die('Error to connect to the database');

    if(mysql_num_rows(@$results) > 0) // not available
    {
        echo '<div id="msg">Login Successful !</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div id="msg">Not Register Yet !</div>';
    }

}?>
```

What i mean is, i want show message success or failed from ***"login.php"*** call DIV with ID msg where that DIV in "index.php" file.  in index.php will show when login using ajax show up when success or failed. But i want call this DIV from login.php page.

Can i do this? Thank you

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out .

```
$.post('index.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data){
    $("#msg").html(data)
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

For more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866106/jquery-how-to-populate-a-div-in-another-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your login.php to response as `JSON`

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST)
{
    $username   = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $query = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".strtolower($username)."'";
    $results = mysql_query( $query) or die('Error to connect to the database');

    if(mysql_num_rows(@$results) > 0) // not available
    {
        $res = array('id'=>'msg', 'data'=>'Login Successful !');//here you can pass the id you need to change it and the new html data 
    }
    else
    {
        $res = array('id'=>'msg', 'data'=>'Not Register Yet !');//here also you can pass the id you need to change it and the new html data 
    }

}
header('Content-type: application/json');// to response as JSON code in the header
echo json_encode($res);// to encode the result string as JSON code
?>
```

And login.js would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Loading4').hide();    
});

function ajax-login(){
    var cUusername = $("#cUsername").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if(cUsername.length > 2){
        $('#Loading4').show();
        $.post("login.php", {
            cUsername: $('#cUsername').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
        }, function(response){
            $('#Info4').fadeOut();
             $('#Loading4').hide();
             setTimeout(function(){
                   finishAjax4(response['id'], response['data'])
             },450);
        });
        return false;
    }
}

function finishAjax4(id, response){

  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Comment: and please as @Shivan Raptor said, "Stop using mysql" it's deprecated and full of threats.... use dbo or mysqli instead.